# Method OnTriggerStay2D() works only when player is moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a simple "radiation" field through a trigger but it works only when player in move. Function countes two decimal values.
What could be the problem?

```
decimal radIntensity = 0.001m;

decimal currentDose;

private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D area)
{
     if (area.gameObject.tag == "Player")
     {
         currentDose += radIntensity;
     }

     print($"Current dose: {currentDose} R");
}
```

Comment: You sure you haven't set your console to collapse log?

Comment: Just a sidenote multiply ``radIntensity * Time.deltaTime``, becuase OnTriggerStay2D is called each Frame similar to the Update function resulting in your player taking more damage if they have a faster pc or less damage if they have a slower pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [`RigidBody2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) component there's an option to disable or enable the sleeping mode.

Try to disable it with the [`RigidbodySleepMode2D.NeverSleep`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodySleepMode2D.NeverSleep.html) option.

Answer (score 0):

Also can use a boolean-flag and OnTriggerEnter2D and OnTriggerExit2D. But never sleeping rigidbody is much better

```
bool _flag;
private void Update()
    {
        if (_flag)
        {
            currentDose += radIntensity;
        }
        print($"Current dose {currentDose} R");
    }
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D area)
    {
        if (area.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            _flag = true;
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            _flag = !true;
        }
```